# Warning Apache Beam when using coroutine

Tags: kotlin, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

My **Kotlin** project is using **Apache Beam** with [PubsubIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html). Everything is working fine until I try to implement **coroutine**.

This works :

```kotlin
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) { ... }
```

This works, but triggers warnings :

```kotlin
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> { ... }
```

```
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Oct 22, 2021 11:53:52 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Oct 22, 2021 11:53:52 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Oct 22, 2021 11:53:52 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Oct 22, 2021 11:53:53 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
Oct 22, 2021 11:53:53 AM com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClient <init>
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

Warning messages are spamming (*~5/6 messages per second*) and I can't find a way to get rid of these. I don't use anything related to `AbstractGoogleClient` in my code, so I don't really know how to fix this on my side :

```kotlin
@Suppress
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
  launch {
    while (true) {
      delay(1000L)
      println("Testing...")
    }
  }

  val options =
      PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(*args).withValidation().`as`(PipelineOptions::class.java)
  val p = Pipeline.create(options)

  p.apply<PCollection<String>>(
        "Read messages from Pub/Sub",
        PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.inputSubscription)
    )
    .apply("Processing", ParDo.of(ProcessData()))

  p.run()
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is similar to this [Github issue here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/1062)

###### Set the application name to be used in the UserAgent header of each request or null for none.

UserAgent header example:

`"{application name} Google-API-Java-Client Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.22.0 (gzip)"`

Maybe something like this will resolve the warning (as it indicates **Call Builder#setApplicationName**)

```
val service = Builder(...)
       .setHttpRequestInitializer(credentials)
       .setApplicationName("Your app name")
       .build()
```